# Python OpenCV IP camera feed Errors

Tags: python, opencv

Me and my buddy have been working on a project involving the OpenCV class in python.
We are using linux Debian with an 8 core Intel i5 processor and 16 GB ram.
We have six 4K 20 fps, hikvision IP cameras running in our local environment for this that we are trying to retrieve video from.

We have been struggling with error messages that we cannot seem to solve.
The errors look like the ones in red, the top right window is a check on netstat and the bottom right one is our tcp_rmem parameters.

The errors[image: Setup]

Now, there is alot of data being sent here each second, and we know that the problem probably is that our program isn't fast enough to process all this data, so the tcp buffer is getting overloaded.

We have tried:

- Reducing bitrate on cameras => Bad quality images
- Increasing tcp_rmem values => Just postpones the errors, inflow > outflow :(
- Tried different codecs, h264, h265, h264+(Hikvision) => Same problems
- Purchased better hardware => Worked better, but is it the only solution?
- Scaling down our code to simply read the frame and then continue to the next frame(no fancy in between work) => Same problems

Has anyone any idea on how to resolve this?
Can you set a limit to what is the smallest tcp packet that the OS will recieve ? So to not have it overload the buffer. It's fine to have it drop some frames for our purposes.

Thanks in advance!
Emil

Comment: What's your current goal? Do you need to process the data in real time (I'd say doing any sort of meaningful processing on 3 GiB of pixel data per second is going to be anything but trivial)? If you just need to save the data as the first step, ditch OpenCV, and look for a way to store the compressed stream directly to the disk without having to decode and re-encode the frames (which using OpenCV will involve, and is very costly -- that's why changing codecs didn't really make any difference).

Comment: Can you share the code or command you tried ?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for libraries that can be used to retrieve compressed stream without decoding ?